# How to find out DOM and CSS address to an element for Selenium?

Tags: css, dom, selenium

I have a following element (Login box):

```
<input type="text" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px; width: 180px;" id="ctl00_Content_ctl00_Login2_UserName" maxlength="50" name="ctl00$Content$ctl00$Login2$UserName">
```

Because I have a Firebug, if I right click on on the element it gives me XPath address (`//*[@id="ctl00_Content_ctl00_Login2_UserName"]`).

As per [Selenium website](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_selenese_commands.html#locating-elements), I am suppose to be able to click on the element also by **DOM** and by **CSS**. How do I do it? Is there an easy tool (browser add-on) available for this purpose? I just don't want to be limited by id and xpath alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS locator would be

`css=#ctl00_Content_ctl00_Login2_UserName`

DOM Locator would be

`dom=document.getElementById('ctl00_Content_ctl00_Login2_UserName')`

Comment: I've checked and the both worked. 
Do DOM and CSS [b]always[/b] use ID? What if there is no ID, can I use DOM and CSS?

Comment: Selenium is great in that it allows you to use nearly all of the attributes to find the elements on the page.E.g. if you want something by the CSS class it would be css=.className or by DOM dom=document.getElementsByClassName('class')[indexOfItem]

Answer (score 0):

Another way of formulating the css identifier would be:

```
css=input[id=ctl00_Content_ctl00_Login2_UserName]
```

If you are using the IDE, formulate the identifier and click the "Find" button to ensure the IDE (and RC, in turn) can access the UI element.

Comment: css=#ctl00_Content_ctl00_Login2_UserName
css=input[id=ctl00_Content_ctl00_Login2_UserName]
You guys gave me two versions of CSS locators and they both worked. Are there any other ways as well? Where do I learn more about these CSS locator formats?

Answer (score 0):

You can use firepath. This is a firebug extension and is really good in formulating CSS locators.

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium, a better way to choose elements for asp.net (prior to 4.0) websites is to use an xpath like:

//input[contains(@id,'UserName')]

If you specify the full id as recommended elsewhere, your locator will fail as soon as you wrap the control inside another panel. Of course, your xpath could also fail if you have another input with an id containing UserName, but this is much less likely than you adding another panel wrapper (in a masterpage, for example).

In regards to always using id, the answer is no.  You can use many other types of selectors, and there's no need to use ids in most of them.

See [Selenium reference](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.2/reference.html) and scroll down to where it says "Element Locators" for other types of selectors you can use.